# How to autosize column width in exceljs

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, exceljs

I must to autosize column width with `exceljs`.
My excel must be dynamic and save in Excel only the columns that the user will provide in the request. To this case I provide this syntax:

```
workSheet.getRow(1).values = dto.columns;
```

which save column name on the first row with names provided in `dto.columns`.

But i must set width to each of the column, i try this:

```
for(let i=0; i <= dto.columns.length-1; i++) {
            workSheet.columns = [
                {key: dto.columns[i], width: Object.keys(dto.columns[i]).length}
            ]
        }
```

but this don't set me any with :

can someone tell me how can i create an `autosize` function to this problem?

thanks for any help

Answer (score 27):

You iterate the cells and check the length of each in such a way

```
    worksheet.columns.forEach(function (column, i) {
        let maxLength = 0;
        column["eachCell"]({ includeEmpty: true }, function (cell) {
            var columnLength = cell.value ? cell.value.toString().length : 10;
            if (columnLength > maxLength ) {
                maxLength = columnLength;
            }
        });
        column.width = maxLength < 10 ? 10 : maxLength;
    });
```

Comment: what is the "eachCell" is this a property of some sort?

Comment: @AsmaRahimAliJafri eachCell is similar to forEach for array in JS.....basically it iterates over each cell

Comment: but what is columns here in `worksheet.columns.forEach` how to use this please be more specific !

Comment: @KunalPandey columns is the array of columns in your sheet

Answer (score 10):

It works for me, you can do it like this:

```
private AdjustColumnWidth(worksheet) {
  worksheet.columns.forEach(column => {
    const lengths = column.values.map(v => v.toString().length);
    const maxLength = Math.max(...lengths.filter(v => typeof v === 'number'));
    column.width = maxLength;
  });
}
```

Comment: I found this works well and is more succinct than the other options.  Adding a little padding based on the fact that I was using `autoFilter` and factoring in the header's width made it just about perfect: `column.width = Math.max(Math.max(...lengths.filter(v => typeof v === 'number')) + 2, column.header.length + 6);`

Answer (score 2):

If you find that other solutions aren't working when there's a `numFmt` involved, especially for `Date` values, here is a solution that uses some of the concepts previously suggested, as well as the SSF library to format cell values with `numFmt` before getting the length.

```js
import { format } from 'ssf';

// Convert Date object to Microsoft serial date aka ms date aka OA date
const dateToSerial = (date: Date): number => {
  const timezoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset() / (60 * 24);
  const msDate = date.getTime() / 86400000 + (25569 - timezoneOffset);
  return msDate;
};

const autoFitColumn = (column: ExcelJS.Column) => {
  const numFmt = column.numFmt;
  let maxLength = 6;
  column.eachCell({ includeEmpty: true }, (cell: ExcelJS.Cell) => {
    let columnLength: number;
    if (numFmt && cell.value != undefined) {
      switch (cell.type) {
        case ExcelJS.ValueType.Date:
          const serialDate = dateToSerial(cell.value as Date);
          const formattedDate = format(numFmt, serialDate);
          columnLength = formattedDate.length;
          break;
        case ExcelJS.ValueType.Number:
          const formattedNumber = format(numFmt, cell.value as Number);
          columnLength = formattedNumber.length;
          break;
        default:
          const formatted = format(numFmt, cell.value);
          columnLength = formatted.length;
          break;
      }
    } else {
      columnLength = cell.text.length;
    }
    maxLength = Math.max(maxLength, columnLength);
  });
  column.width = maxLength + 2;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Ashish's answer is working. Thanks

To ignore serial no if you have in first cell:

refer:

```
worksheet.columns.forEach(function (column, i) {
    if(i!==0)
    {
        var maxLength = 0;
        column["eachCell"]({ includeEmpty: true }, function (cell) {
            var columnLength = cell.value ? cell.value.toString().length : 10;
            if (columnLength > maxLength ) {
                maxLength = columnLength;
            }
        });
        column.width = maxLength < 10 ? 10 : maxLength;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer may be coming in a little bit too late, but i hope this helps out. The above examples work just fine. Just a little modification to ensure that all works well. To prevent overriding of column withs, this is what works for me

```
 worksheet.columns.forEach(function (column) {
              var dataMax = 0;
              column.eachCell({ includeEmpty: true }, function (cell) { 
                dataMax = cell.value?cell.value.toString().length:0;
                if(dataMax <= (column.header.length+2) ){
                    if(column.width > dataMax){
                        //retain its default width
                    } else {
                        column.width = column.header.length+3;
                    }
                } else {
                    column.width = dataMax+3;
                   column.header.length = dataMax+3;
                }
                dataMax = 0;
              })
              
            });
```

Comment: column.header is undefined for me.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```js
worksheet.columns.forEach((column) => {
    let maxLength = 0;
    column["eachCell"]({ includeEmpty: true }, (cell) => {
        const columnLength = cell.value ? cell.value.toString().length + 3 : 10;
        if (cell.type === ExcelJS.ValueType.Date) {
            maxLength = 20;
        }
        else if (columnLength > maxLength) {
            maxLength = columnLength + 3;
        }
    });
    column.width = maxLength < 10 ? 10 : maxLength;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To automatically change the column width we basically need to find the length of the values that we add into the excel sheet, and then set the width to that. After playing around for a while I believe the following should work:

First let's iterate through each column of the worksheet:

```
wokrsheetName.column.forEach(col => {});
//Note that col => {} is just a shorter way to write function(col) {}
```

Next we need to iterate through the values withing each column. This is fortunately stored under the 'value' property. However, since your worksheet will probably contain more than one value per key (i.e. the "Name" column will contain several names, not just one), we will have to look for the value with the greatest length (i.e. the longest name)

```
//we iterate through all the columns of the worksheet (i.e. name, surname, etc. whatever your worksheet might contain)
wokrsheetName.column.forEach(col => {
//next we find the value with the largest length
//we can access the values through col.value
//we can use the reduce function to find the largest value
        const largestValueLength = col.values.reduce((maxWidth, value) => {
//the maxWidth starts at 0
//we compare the length of the value to the maxWidth and if it's larger, the maxWidth will update to the larger value.
//It will do this for each value in every cell, and only the largest value will remain
                if (value && value.length > maxWidth) {
                    return value.length;
                }
                return maxWidth;
            }, 0);
//finally we can set the width of the column to the new number
//we can access the width through the col.width
      col.width = maxColumnWidth;
    });
```

Sometimes the header might be larger, so you might want to compare the header as well, we can simply update the function:

```
worksheetName.columns.forEach(col => {
//we can access the headers through the col.header
        const headerLength = col.header.length;
//the reduce functions stays the same
        const largestValueLength = col.values.reduce((maxWidth, value) => {
            if (value && value.length > maxWidth) {
                return value.length;
            }
            return maxWidth;
        }, 0);
//finally we simply use Math.max to choose the larger of the two
        col.width = Math.max(headerLength, maxColumnWidth)
    });
```

If you want you could always add a number to the equation to give some padding to the cells. Ultimately the code should look something like this:

```
worksheetName.columns.forEach(col => {

    const headerLength = col.header.length;

    const largestValueLength = col.values.reduce((maxWidth, value) => {
        if (value && value.length > maxWidth) {
            return value.length;
        }
        return maxWidth;
    }, 0);

    col.width = Math.max(headerLength, maxColumnWidth) +2;

});
```